# arraylist modify at specific index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `ArrayLists`. As below example shows.

```
ArrayList<String> listVarName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listVarValue = new ArrayList<String>();

listVarName.add("One");
listVarName.add("Two");
listVarName.add("Three");
listVarName.add("Four");

listVarValue.add("Content of One");
listVarValue.add("Content of Two");
listVarValue.add("Content of Three");
listVarValue.add("Content of Four");

//Code to append the value
int index = listVarName.indexOf("Two");
String oldVal = listVarValue.get(index);
listVarValue.remove(index);
listVarValue.add(index, oldVal+" APPENDED TEXT");

System.out.println(listVarName.toString());
System.out.println(listVarValue.toString());
```

Output Before appending:

```
[One, Two, Three, Four]
[Content of One, Content of Two, Content of Three, Content of Four]
```

Output after appending:

```
[One, Two, Three, Four]
[Content of One, Content of Two APPENDED TEXT, Content of Three, Content of Four]
```

In above code *listVarName* is *key* and *listVarValue* is *value*.

So I am trying to *append* `listVarValue` where its index matches the index of `listVarName`. So I am getting old value of `listVarValue` and adding new value to it and then removing old value from list and inserting new value to its old position.

Above code is working fine. My question is that is there any better way instead the code I have used to append the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're concerned about the list modification rather than general structure, yes - there's a better way.

Rather than using `remove` then `add`, use [`List.set(index, element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29):

```
String oldVal = listVarValue.get(index);
listVarValue.set(index, oldVal + " APPENDED TEXT");
```

As well as being simpler code, this is more efficient - adding and removing in an `ArrayList` each involve copying all the rest of the elements within the backing array to their new position - whereas `set` just involves changing a single element in the backing array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Map<String,String>` instead of 2 `ArrayList`. At the end you can get them separately as collection by calling `keySet()` and `values()`

```
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("one", "Content of One");
    map.put("Two", "Content of Two");
    map.put("Three", "Content of Three");
    map.put("Four", "Content of Four");

    map.put("Two", map.get("Two") + " APPEND TEXT");
    System.out.println(map.values());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer(and +1). Your answer suggest a better way of doing what I was trying to do. I have implemented `Map` in above program and its  better than using two `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these two lines

```
listVarValue.remove(index);
listVarValue.add(index, oldVal+" APPENDED TEXT");
```

You can use

```
listVarValue.set(index,oldVal+" APPENDED TEXT")
```